# Unable to find file path of powershell file from a .bat file only when running as administrator

Tags: powershell, batch-file

When I run the following code from a bat file, I get an error saying Access is denied because I am not running as administrator.

```
C:\Windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\powershell.exe -ExecutionPolicy Bypass -File ".\test.ps1"
```

[not as admin](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vFfUQ.png)

When I run the .bat file as administrator, I get an error saying it can't find the powershell file.

[as admin](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DVTtE.png)

The second line of the error message when I don't run the bat file as admin shows that it is able to find the file path, so I'm confused as to why it can't find the path as administrator.

Answer (score 2):

You're referring to your PowerShell script file, `test.ps1`, as being located in the *current directory* (`.\`)
Unless you explicitly set the current directory beforehand or use an absolute path (see below), your batch file won't work robustly.

Case in point:

- Opening a batch file from File Explorer by double-clicking it makes the directory *in which the batch file is located* the current directory, so if your `.ps1` script is located in the *same* directory, the call will work in *this case*.
- By contrast, when you open the batch file *with elevation*, by right-clicking and selecting `Run as administrator`, *`C:\Windows\System32` will be the current directory*, and your call will fail.

**Solutions:**

- Either: Explicitly make the batch file's own directory the current directory:

  ```
  pushd "%~dp0"
  C:\Windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\powershell.exe -ExecutionPolicy Bypass -File ".\test.ps1"
  popd
  ```

  - Note:

    - Using `pushd` is the most robust solution, because `cd /d "%~dp0"` won't work if your batch file is invoke via a *UNC path*. Unlike `cd`, `pushd` *automatically maps a drive letter* to the given UNC path, which is necessary, because `cmd.exe` doesn't allow direct use of UNC paths as working directories; `pushd` starts from `Z:` going backwards to find an unused drive letter.

      - However, a paired `popd` call is necessary in order to *release* that drive letter again, whereas if you combine `cd /d "%~dp0"` with `setlocal` (see below), no further action is necessary.
      - If you don't need to support invocation via UNC paths, you may alternatively use `cd /d "%~dp0" || exit /b`, which simply aborts execution with exit code `1` if such an attempt is made.
    - In either case, it is advisable to place `setlocal` at the start of your batch file, so that the change in working directory is *limited to your batch file* and doesn't affect the caller; e.g., start your batch file with `@echo off & setlocal`.
      Note that `setlocal` also makes any *variables* created or modified in your batch file local to that script, which, however, is normally also desirable.
- Or, if the current directory isn't important as long as you target the right `.ps1` file:

  ```
  C:\Windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\powershell.exe -ExecutionPolicy Bypass -File "%~dp0test.ps1"
  ```

**As for the syntax of `%~dp0`**:

`%~dp0` expands to the full path of the batch file's own directory; the syntax is explained in the output from `call /?`, but, in short: `%0` refers to the batch file name or path *as invoked*, and `~dp` modifies it to report (only) the drive (`d`) and full directory path (`p`).